# How to install terra / raster packages in R Google Colab?

Tags: r, package, google-colaboratory, raster, terra

I'm trying to install `terra` package in R Google Colab, but it is not working.

It returns:

```
“installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status”
```

I tried the solutions found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953303/unable-to-install-specific-packages-in-googlecolab-with-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72128073/20455379), i.e., trying to install dependencies like GDAL via `system("apt install libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev" )` but it does not work.

Is it possible to run `terra` in Google Colab (or even `raster`) packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install `terra` on Google Colab using the code below. It did take about 5-10 minutes for the library to install.

1. In Google Colab, select "Runtime", "Change runtime type" and select "R" under "Runtime type".
2. Install `terra` per the instructions on the module's [GitHub page](https://github.com/rspatial/terra):

```
install.packages("Rcpp")

Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")
remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")

#read in packages
library(terra)
```

3. Test that the module is imported and working, the code block below is from the [rspatial.org](https://rspatial.org/pkg/4-algebra.html) site:

```
## terra 1.7.36
# create an empty SpatRaster
r <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10)
# assign values to cells
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
s <- r + 10
s <- sqrt(s)
s <- s * r + 5
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
r <- round(r)
r <- r == 1
r
```

Output is below:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source(s)   : memory
name        : lyr.1 
min value   : FALSE 
max value   :  TRUE
```

Additional code block:

```
x <- rast(ncol=36, nrow=18, xmin=-1000, xmax=1000, ymin=-100, ymax=900)
res(x)
## [1] 55.55556 55.55556

res(x) <- 100
res(x)
```

Output:

```
55.555555555555655.5555555555556
100100
```

Comment: Mine did not work :(, I got ```Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)```. Then ```Warning message: “dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available”```. Then ```Warning message in install.packages("terra",repos="https://rspatial.r-universe.dev"):"installation of package "terra" had non-zero exit status". Error in library(terra): there is no package called `terra`. Traceback: 1. library(terra).``` To do that I opened a new notebook and change to R like you said. Do you have any other tips? Thank you!!!

Comment: Odd, it worked yesterday, had the same issue as you just now.

Went back and edited the code to install `terra` from source. Seems to work now, also put it up on [GitHub](https://github.com/ad17171717/Stack-Overflow-Answers/blob/main/Stack-Overflow-Answers/How_to_install_terra_raster_packages_in_R_Google_Colab%3F.ipynb) in case you want to try it.

Comment: Oh, so it was not only here! Thank you very much, this new approach from source worked :).